# Stalin's absent-minded signature resulted in Hotel Moskva having two designs?

Tags: soviet-union, architecture

Is this explanation true/false/unverifiable?

[Four Seasons Hotel Moscow (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Seasons_Hotel_Moscow):

> The original hotel was notable for its use of two different designs for the wings off the central structure. The most popular (possibly apocryphal) explanation is that Shchusev submitted to Stalin a single drawing of the façade, with one half showing one design, and the other half a different designs for the wings of the building. However, Stalin put his signature exactly in the middle of the drawing, likely not observing the two choices. Afraid of informing Stalin that he had failed to select a design, the decision was made to simply constructed one wing of each on either side of the building. One included large windows and a more ornate façade, while the other maintained smaller windows and the simpler details of the rest of the hotel's façade.

Comment: Russian wikipedia claims that this is a myth and Stalin never was involved in such decisions. It says the weird design is due to the fact that left part of the building started to crack and they had to redesign it and built right part differently, as a result. There is no reference unfortunately...